# External searching algorithm

Tags: sorting, sortedlist, external-sorting

If I have a very large sorted list stored in external storage. Assuming this list cannot be brought into internal memory, what would be a good searching algorithm that looks for a key in this list in pseudo code? what would be the time complexity?, also what major factors should be considered when designing this algorithm?

Comment: You could create key specific index files and then create some domain specific language...lets call it SQL to query the data in a structured form. Then you could spend time writing more and more extras. But wait - this was done already. It is called a database.

Comment: In many databases, a key specific file is involved, but it's only one key for every k records, where k might be something like 64 (could be less or more), which would get a lookup to within 64 records, which would then be read sequentially, with just one initial random access. Back in the days of mainframes and limited memory, nested indexes were used, such as indexes to indexes to records.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your external storage is just a plain array of constant size records stored in a file and your programming language allows to [memory map the file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), you can use the usual [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Say, in C++ you

1. [mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) the file take void* pointers to the begin and end of the
   mmap-ed file,
2. cast the pointers to your record type
3. and then search for a record using [std::lower_bound()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/), which is one of the standard binary search implementations.

Note that memory mapping a file does not mean loading the whole file into internal memory, instead the system will automatically load the necessary pages from the file into a cache of loaded pages with smart policies of keeping the size of cached pages within available memory bounds.

This is standard practice for searching in sorted files and there is no reason for re-designing it (well, to the best of my knowledge). The complexity of the binary search algorithm in external memory depends on the external storage model, buffering/paging strategy etc, but for your hard drive you can still assume it's in usual O(log N). I'd recommend you search for [out-of-core algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-core_algorithm) and data structures tutorials and libraries.